# How to make Router display urls from Multiple apps in Browsable API root view in Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django project with five apps all inside apps/ folder as in the image

Each app inside apps/ there is an urls.py file, where I am using Django-rest-framework Routers to have the URLS generated, and along with a web-browsable api view, with

So,
www.mysite.com/apps/appA -->shows a list of URLS for appA
www.mysite.com/apps/appB -->shows a list of URLS for appB

How do I add to www.mysite.com/ -- a link to go to these specific pages above?

Thanks

Comment: There is now a newer question with answers to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483282/django-rest-framework-combining-routers-from-different-apps?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to create a urls.py for the apps folder that includes the urls.py for each app inside of apps. Then in your projects root urls.py, include the urls.py in apps/. Post your current urls if you don't understand.