# Django REST Framework combining routers from different apps

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a project that spans multiple apps:

```
./project/app1
./project/app2
./project/...
```

Each app has a router for Django REST Framework to incorporate the parts of the API provided by that app:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .views import ThingViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'things', ThingViewSet, base_name='thing')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Because the apps are separate, my top-level URLs file (`./project/urls.py`) includes each of the URLs files from the separate apps:

```
url(r'^api/app1/', include('app1.urls', namespace='a1')),
url(r'^api/app2/', include('app2.urls', namespace='a2')),
```

This means that Django REST Framework shows a separate API root for each app. What I would like, however, is a unified API structure, so that if I navigate to `http://example.com/api/` I see the full list of all URLs that are available at that level of the hierarchy.

I presume there is a way to include all my separate routers defined in the individual `urls.py` files for each app into a single router, but I can't find documentation on how to do this. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Another solution is to use `SimpleRouter` to define routers for individual apps. Then, use a customized `DefaultRouter` to include app specific routes. This way all of the app specific url definitions will stay in the corresponding app.

Lets say you have two apps named "app1" and "app2" each of these apps have a directory named "api" and in this directory there is a file named "urls" that contain all your route definitions.

`├── project/
│   ├── api_urls.py
│   ├── app1
│   │   ├── api
│   │   │   ├── urls.py
│   ├── app2
│   │   ├── api
│   │   │   ├── urls.py
│   ├── patches
│   │   ├── routers.py`

use `patches/router.py` to define a class named `DefaultRouter` that inherits from `rest_framework.routers.DefaultRouter`.

```
from rest_framework import routers

class DefaultRouter(routers.DefaultRouter):
    """
    Extends `DefaultRouter` class to add a method for extending url routes from another router.
    """
    def extend(self, router):
        """
        Extend the routes with url routes of the passed in router.

        Args:
             router: SimpleRouter instance containing route definitions.
        """
        self.registry.extend(router.registry)
```

Fill your api urls with route definitions like

```
"""
URL definitions for the api.
"""
from patches import routers

from app1.api.urls import router as app1_router
from app2.api.urls import router as app2_router

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.extend(app1_router)
router.extend(app2_router)
```

Comment: Or even simpler you can just import your router for a particular app `from app1.urls import router as app1router` and then register this router with your default router in the main urls.py file `router.registry.extend(app1router.registry)` and then you don't have to subclass anything.

Comment: Indeed.  Good comment.  No need to subclass.

Comment: Recommend this comment's solution as well.

Comment: where should the 2nd piece of code go? in the main project URLs file or individual app URLs? Also, I see DefaultRouter being used without import. It's unclear.

Comment: @abicrazieeee The 2nd piece of code should go in the main projects `urls.py` file.

Answer (score 17):

This gets all the ViewSet routes listed on the base API URL.

It defines the routes as a list in the respective included app.urls so they can be registered elsewhere.

After including them in the base urls.py, the nested list of lists is built and looped through to register all routes at the same level in the API

```
# foo.urls
routeList = (
    (r'foos', FooViewSet),
)

# barBaz.urls
routeList = (
    (r'bars', BarViewSet),
    (r'bazs', BazViewSet),
)

# urls
from rest_framework import routers
from foo import urls as fooUrls
from barBaz import urls as barBazUrls

routeLists = [
    fooUrls.routeList,
    barBazUrls.routeList,
]

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
for routeList in routeLists:
    for route in routeList:
        router.register(route[0], route[1])
```

Results:

```
{
    "foo": "http://localhost:8000/foos/",
    "bar": "http://localhost:8000/bars/",
    "baz": "http://localhost:8000/bazs/",
}
```

This also has less repetition in each file, and arguably makes it easier to read.

Also, it remains completely decoupled.

If the included app is used elsewhere, the same method can be used internally to register it's own routes without being included anywhere.

Just drop the outside loop

```
routeList = (
    (r'bars', BarViewSet),
    (r'bazs', BazViewSet),
)

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
for route in routeList:
    router.register(route[0], route[1])
```

Comment: Excellent idea. The only room for improvement here is that I think there could be name collisions in this (if two apps tried to register the 'bars' name, for instance). But for a starting point, this is a great approach. Thanks!

Comment: That's true.  Would be a simple change.  Instead of a route being ```(r'foos', FooViewSet),```  you can namespace it like ```(r'foo/route1', FooViewSet),```  Then as long as your app names are unique, there should be no collisions.

Answer (score 7):

I ended up creating a single URLs file that contains all the routes I want at urls_api_v1.py:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'app1/foos', FooViewSet, base_name='foo')
router.register(r'app2/bars', BarViewSet, base_name='bar')
router.register(r'app2/bazs', BazViewSet, base_name='baz')
```

As a side effect, this allowed me to get rid of all the individual urls.py files in each app, which you would normally want but in this case the entire collection of apps needs a unified URL structure and so removal is more sensible.

I then reference it from `urls.py`:

```
import api_v1
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...,
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(api_v1, namespace='api-v1')),
)
```

Now if I ever want to change routes for v2, I can just include a v2 URLs file as well and eventually deprecate the v1 file.

Comment: But your apps are self-contained, so they should have their own urls.py. That is my case too, and I would like to avoid moving the all urls to a centralized one, which makes no sense. How to unify the URLs and at the same time keep the apps separated? Surely there is a way of including already existing urls.py from different apps?

Comment: I haven't found such a way, thought I stopped looking after I figured out this much. I believe this is a reasonable way to do this because the *apps* are separated, but the API is not. By having REST Framework figure out the URL structure on an app-by-app basis, all I am doing is combining those into a single, top-level arrangement that is not specific to any app.

This is not that much different from having a top-level urls.py that brings together each of the separate apps' urls.py files into their own namespace.

Comment: I respectfully disagree: the API organization is responsibility of each  app, and the top app needs no knowledge about the URL tree of each app. That is what API discoverability (and api_root) is about. The top project will just plug the different sub-APIs as it sees fit, in the top endpoint that it chooses. And everything should work then, including the option of browsing the whole API starting from the api root.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I don't think that is universally true. For my case, for instance, I have multiple apps that are loosely coupled. Some clients only spend time in one area or another, but some clients cross boundaries out of necessity. From a development perspective, the apps are independent or at most loosely coupled; this facilitates easier development, testing, and management of data. Each app provides a small number of ViewSets, and a single urls.py file bundles the entirety of the codebase into a single client-visible API.

Comment: If they were truly independent apps, then I would have no qualms about having truly independent views into the API, one for each app. That would be handled by simply importing the urls.py for each app the traditional way.

Comment: This is fine, but all your apps' urls are listed together in the root (flat, as opposed to nested) and if you decide to add an XML renderer the entity names will have slashes in them which isn't valid XML.

Comment: The flat API is what I was going for, so for my case this works. Hadn't thought about the XML case, since I'm only using JSON... good point.

Answer (score 7):

[@Colton Hicks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5728276/colton-hicks) comment

Let's say we have 2 apps (permissions, users) inside "apps folder". Then we can do something like this:

```
from apps.users.api.urls import router as users_router
from apps.permissions.api.urls import router as permissions_router


router = DefaultRouter()
router.registry.extend(users_router.registry)
router.registry.extend(permissions_router.registry)
```

Comment: Is `extend()` new? On casual Googling I don't see anything about it in the docs.

Comment: `extend` is in python std library its works the same as `+` of two lists

Answer (score 6):

You can use `router.registry.extend(app_router.registry)`, total example:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from app1.rest import router as app1_router
from app2.rest import router as app2_router

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.registry.extend(app1_router.registry)
router.registry.extend(app2_router.registry)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing a SimpleRouter you just concatenate its urls with the urlpatterns list

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'import-project', ImportProject, base_name='di-integ')
```

On the main urls.py file

```
from di_apiary_integration.urls import router as di_integration_routers
```

To register the URL's you can do:

```
url(r'^di-integration/', include(di_integration_routers.urls)),
```

or

```
urlpatterns += di_integ_router.urls
```

Both will work!

*Important*

ImportProject needs to be either a ModelViewSet or a ViewSet, if you create this as simple APIView you will need to register that as normal CBV View using as_view()