# Howto combine DjangoRestFramework routers for different apps

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use Django 2.1 and DRF and a planning a quite larger application with many plugged-in apps. I'd like to have ONE `/api` URL for the DRF as endpoint, but allow each app to have a special model exposed over the REST endpoint, e.g.:

In the main `urls.py`:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    # ...
]
```

and in `foo_app/urls.py`:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'foomodel', FooModelViewSet)
```

Now, `/api/foomodel` produces a `404` Error. The foo_model/urls.py gets imported (a print statement there is printed at Django start), and all the other `foo_model.urlpattern[path...]` are recognized and work fine.

How can I define custom api model endpoints for a central api REST endpoint? I didn't find anything in the documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I simply achieved this by extending the router registries.

root `urls.py`

```py
from ad.urls import router as ad_router

main_router = routers.DefaultRouter()
main_router.registry.extend(ad_router.registry)
```

`ad.urls.py`

```py
from .api.urls import router as api_router

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.registry.extend(api_router.registry)
```

`ad.api.urls.py`

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'ad', AdViewSet)
```

Comment: whow, seems nice, I'll have a look at this ASAP.

Comment: This is at least a bit more in the direction I want. I can't use `main_router.registry.extend(ad_router.registry)`, as main_router doesn't know about ad_router (or other plugins). But I can maybe solve that using the GDAPS plugin system. Thanks.

Comment: This is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40904241/818131

Answer (score 2):

In your main `urls.py` you would do something like this.
(This is for Django 1.8)

```py
urlpatterns += patterns('',
url(r'^api/', include(patterns('',
    url(r'^foo_app/', include('foo_app.urls')),
    url(r'^bar_app/', include('bar_app.urls')),
    url(r'^test_app/', include('test_app.urls')),
))))
```

this allows you to access all your endpoints this way

```py
localhost:8000/api/foo_app/<foo_app_endpoint>
localhost:8000/api/bar_app/<bar_app_endpoint>
localhost:8000/api/bar_app/<test_app_endpoint>
```

Comment: Ok. The good old `include` thing. But that's not pluggable. I want my **app** to bring it's URL pattern along, and not add all plugins manually in the main `urls.py` file. I wrote my own plugin system (GDAPS, alpha,, on pypi) which could deal with that. But I thought that with the "router" of the rest_framework this could be done easier? Do I really haveto use the "pattern" adding additionally? What is the router then for?