# Project structure for API only Django project

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to create a Django based backend providing an API using [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) only. The admin interface is the only visual interface I need for end users. The API shall be used by/integrated with a JS frontend. The backend consists of several parts like *configuration*, *visualization*, etc. According to design best practices I'd first create a Django project `my_project` with `django-admin startproject my_project .` and add an app per part with `python manage.py startapp configuration`, `python manage.py startapp visualization`, etc. (In the [django-rest-framework quickstart](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#quickstart) there is generated one Django app.)

To me it's not clear how I have to adopt the Django design best practice of using apps to RESTful API based JS frontend integration. In case I want to integrate the backend with a JS frontend how should I structure my codebase? Should I create apps `configuration`, `visualization`, ... (I don't create template based views) and define corresponding models with a single RESTful API. Where should I place the API sources w.r.t. project structure? How should I map the API to models?

Answer (score 6):

DRF extends Django views and sort of replaces forms with serializers. So you can use exactly the same structure with Django. Or if you like, you can move the DRF modules to a separate `api` package either for each app or project-wide. It all depends on you. But to keep it simple since it's an API only project, you can just use the normal Django app structure with DRF modules flat in the apps

Comment: RIght, but what are the implications of (a) project-wide `api` package, (b) app-specific `api` package, (c) app-specific use of DRF with views? I've used Django templating only, no JS frontend framework integration until now and would like to prevent from possible issues poping up later due to this design decission.

Comment: @thinwybk The only one with implications that I can think of is the project-wide api package. If for some reason you decide to go modular and split out some of the apps into separate third-party apps, then it would take more time to restructure the code and split out the apps. Apart from that, I don't see other real issues. On the other hand it has the advantahe of being able to group your APIs project-wide into `internal API`, `public API` etc.  I have seen projects with each of the 3 cases.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'd like to modularize as much as possible as long as it does not prevent from providing a public API as well. Is there no way to provide a common public API consisting of a public subset of app-specific APIs somehow?

Comment: Of course you can. I was just saying that was easier. It all depends on the level of the differences. If it's just the URL path that is different, then you can define a new public API urls.py. If the differences are in the API logic, then you can have concrete views for each concrete API and then collect them in different urls.py

Comment: The highest rated comment (`from app1.urls import router as app1router`, `router.registry.extend(app1router.registry)`) from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40904241/5308983 is relevant w.r.t. composing a single API from different app APIs.